# Wordpress admin Posts lists filters

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, filter, advanced-custom-fields

I want to add a filters in my posts list because i add a checkbox Custom field in every post to set if the post is featured or not.

On the Posts list, i created a new colomn where i display YES if the post in featured and NO if the post is not.

But, how can i make a dropdown list filters with a checkbox ACF?

I think i need the metakey of the checkbox and the value, but i cant figure out... i have try with (true,false) as the values and featured as the metakey (featured is the field name of the checkbox ACF) but still not working... anybody have an idea?

Comment: Showing code usually helps

Comment: nm... i remove checkbox and i used true/false... with a value of 1 or 0 and metakey as the field name it was working perfectly!